# Ping target through ssh tunnel

Tags: ping, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect from source server S to my target server T. However connection to T is restricted to only from intermediate server I. Since S can't connect to T, I have created a ssh tunnel from S to T via I using:

`ssh -N -f -L port:T:22 I`

Now I can connect to T using:

`ssh -p port user@localhost`

But my problem is that I have to ping to the target T. How can I ping using tunneling.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903002/can-i-use-http-tunnel-to-ping-or-traceroute-through-a-proxy-with-firewall

Comment: That was the first result that showed up when I googled "ping through ssh tunnel". How did you miss it?

Comment: @Barmer Saw that thread before posting here, but it needs curl and also I'm using this ping test in a script and that script at this time have only tunnel port number. So wanted to if I can ping using only port

Comment: But it answers your question: you can't ping through a tunnel. It uses `curl` to test the webserver _instead_ of pinging. You need to find some other way to test the server.

Comment: Down voted. What was wrong in question? Down voters have to put a comment to show whats wrong in question

Comment: Maybe because it was posted to the wrong site, it's not a programming question. superuser.com is more appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

You can't ping through a tunnel. SSH tunnels can only pass TCP connections, ping uses ICMP.

You could run ping on the intermediate server via SSH:

```
ssh I ping T
```