# urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection [Errno 65] No route to host

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to use proxies from https://proxy.webshare.io/. But keep getting errors.

```
def extract(proxy):
    global pcount
    # ua is fake user-agent
    headers={'User-Agent': ua.chrome}
    auth = HTTPProxyAuth("******", "**********")
    r = requests.get('https://www.url.com', headers=headers, proxies={'http':"http://" + str(proxy)},auth=auth, timeout=2)
    print(r.status_code)
   
    return proxy

extract('185.*.*.*:7492')
```

the error i am getting is

```
Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0e64c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 65] No route to host')
```

What is the problem? and please did i use it the right way this is my first time using proxies with authentication.

Comment: That's because https://www.url.com does not exist

Comment: @nacho i changed the url because it looks so long and it is a private work

Comment: @TimilehinAdegbulugbe `urllib3` is failing to get a route. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903400/17676984 to debug.